# Centos 6.5 iconv 2.5 glibc

Tags: centos, glibc

I'm using Centos 6.5 x64 for developing purposes. I need to install iconv 2.5 but could not find how.

Centos 6.5 glibc version is 2.12

On Centos 5.9 glibc version is 2.5

Why newer Centos uses older glibc library? How can i update it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CentOS 6.5 uses glibc 2.12, which is a ***NEWER*** release than glibc 2.5.

12 > 5

CentOS 6.5 includes `/usr/bin/iconv` in the glibc-common package.  It should be installed on your system.

Comment: I thought 2.5 means 2.50. Should not it be 2.05?

Comment: No.  The individual numbers in the version string aren't zero-padded.

Comment: Yes I checked after your precious warning. I'll be more carefull on next time. Thank you.